# Is my data interval-censored data or discrete-time data in the context of survival analysis?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to analyze my data using survival analysis in R and I am curious about how to identify my data.

My research is a 11-months longitudinal study and me and my colleagues collected data for almost every 2 months (wave 1-7). Only wave 5 and 6 were 1 month apart, but all others were 2 months apart.

As I understood, if the data are not collected continuously, the researcher can use survival analysis for interval-censored data, and if some data have the same time intervals, then the researcher can use survival analysis for discrete-time data. I also heard that for discrete time data, all time intervals must be equal.

My question is,

1. Even if my data are not collected at exactly the same interval, can I still use survival analysis for discrete time data?
2. If I can use the method for discrete time data, then is it okay to set the time interval to 1 month? Or are 2 month intervals more appropriate?

I have tried to identify my data in both ways, but neither seems to be appropriate.

Comment: This is not a question for So, since it's not about programming.  But yes, you can use interval censored techniques on this data set.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and sorry for posting in the wrong place...!